# Java implementation of NAT Traversal / HolePunching TPC

Tags: java, android, tcp, p2p, hole-punching

I've been browsing and searching for implementation of a Peer-to-Peer TCP Connection with both clients behind routers, but everything I got was "get more confused"!

**My case is "a little bit simplest", since I already KNOW the local and public IP addresses from both sides**.

So, at this point I just DON'T NEED TO USE THIRD SERVER to discover those informations.

---

Client A: (LocalIP="192.168.0.1", PublicIP="a.a.a.a").

This client will be Listening to connection on port "pppp"

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket("pppp");
serverSocket.setSoTimeout(timeOut);
socket = ClientA.serverSocket.accept();*
```

---

Client B: (LocalIP="10.10.0.1", PublicIP="b.b.b.b")

This client will will try to connect to "Client A" on port "pppp"

```
SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("a.a.a.a", "pppp");
socket.connect(sockaddr, timeOut);
```

---

Of couse it will not work, so **given those informations, how to proceed?**

Comment: That is exactly what nat traversal does. It tricks the router!

Comment: As you mentioned Hole Punching, you need to implement the similar protocol handling mechanism (which rewrites IP Packets with different source IP and forwards to destination as response of their request) on a 3rd party server with public IP (which will actually trick the router). Essentially you will have to go about the RFC in detail to implement this protocol. I couldn't either find any available library for this purpose

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5128